# Running a python program that prints lines from a .txt, getting a random none printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def char_by_char(in_one):

    if in_one == "1":
        file = open("t1.txt")
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            print(line)

def main()
    first_file = input(print("Enter a file to compare(1-6): "))
    char_by_char(first_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my code, when ran it outputs a random None after the print string but still takes the input and prints the lines of my text file. I cannot seem to figure out where this none is coming from.

Comment: you don't need `print()` with `input()`, it is `print()` that returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` function also prints to STDOUT, so your return value from `print("Enter a file..")` which is `None` is also being printed. Get rid of the extra `print` call within input, and pass the string directly into input.

Answer (score 4):

`input` prints its argument itself; you're passing the value `None` as the argument, after the unnecessary call to `print` is evaluated.

```
first_file = input("Enter a file to compare(1-6): ")
```